# when try to write byteArray into file it converts 0B png file , can't get valid file

Tags: android, file, kotlin

> val downloadDir = File(
>                   Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
>                   getString(R.string.app_name)
>               )
>
> ```
>         if (!downloadDir.isDirectory) {
>             //Creates directory named by this file
>             downloadDir.mkdirs()
>         }
>
>         val file = File(downloadDir, fileName)
>
>         try {
>             val ostream = FileOutputStream(file)
>             ostream.write(imageByteArray)
>             ostream.flush()
>             ostream.close() }
> ```

Comment: dos it through Exception ? did you put permission in manifest?

Comment: i added permission in manifest too .

Comment: what about Exceptions?

Comment: there are no exception and files creates but it converts as 0B

Comment: where `imageByteArray` come from? did you check this byte array? dos it have data in it?

Comment: imageByteArray came from webservice and it have data , using it i can load image in imageview too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using following code to save avatar of user in `sdcard`.
you can change the code to suit your needs:

```
 public static String copyToAppDirectory(Context c, Uri uri, String personID) throws IOException {

    File src = new File(uri.getPath());
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), BaseConst.AppDir);
    mediaStorageDir = new File(mediaStorageDir, BaseConst.ImageFolder);

    File dst = new File(mediaStorageDir, personID + ".JPG");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot create Directory!");
        }
    }
    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        in = new FileInputStream(src);
    }

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
    return dst.getPath();
}
```

I hope it helps you